# I need help accessing a JSON object using node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Okay, my code looks as follows

```
const request = require('request');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const HOST = 'https://www.the100.io/api/v1/groups/123/gaming_sessions';

var baseRequest = request.defaults({headers: {'Authorization': 'Token token="I removed the token as its private"'}});

baseRequest(HOST,
               function (err, response, body) {

                   const context = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, 1);
                    console.log(context);


        })
```

It pulls from a site & logs data like this:

```
[
{
    "id": 831354,
    "creator_id": 133819,
    "group_id": 2127,
    "name": "This is a session for Barbosa and I to get a Heroic and Challenge Mode clear. Looking for anyone to help out.",
    "start_time": "2016-11-07T18:15:00.000-08:00",
    "end_time": "2016-11-07T18:15:00.000-08:00",
    "start_date": "2016-11-06T21:00:00.000-08:00",
    "category": "Wrath of the Machine - Heroic Mode",
    "friends_only": false,
    "team_size": 6,
    "platform": "ps4",
    "gamertags": null,
    "bot_created": false,
    "time_zone": null,
    "level": null,
    "sherpa_led": false,
    "sherpa_id": null,
    "strict": false,
    "reddit_url": null,
    "reddit_title": null,
    "reddit_body": null,
    "mic_required": true,
    "group_only": true,
    "party_size": 2,
    "game_id": 1,
    "primary_users_count": 6,
    "light_level": null,
    "platform_formatted": "PS4",
    "creator_gamertag": "richmanbri713",
    "game_name": "Destiny",
    "group_name": "Model UN",
    "display_light_level": null,
    "display_mic_required": "Mic required",
    "formatted_start_date": "2016-11-06-0-0-0",
    "formatted_start_time": "Nov-11",
    "full": true,
    "has_spots_open": false,
    "confirmed_sessions": [
        {
            "id": 3559780,
            "user_id": 194005,
            "gaming_session_id": 831354,
            "reserve_spot": true,
            "user": {
                "id": 194005,
                "gamertag": "CapnBarbosa11",
                "age": 26,
                "level": 40,
                "supporter": false,
                "light_level": 369,
                "hide_age": true,
                "profanity_ok_formatted": null,
                "computed_avatar_api": "img/default-avatar.png",
                "computed_avatar_chat": "https://www.the100.io/default-avatar.png",
                "developer_badge": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3559437,
            "user_id": 142553,
            "gaming_session_id": 831354,
            "reserve_spot": false,
            "user": {
                "id": 142553,
                "gamertag": "ZeroX82",
                "age": 29,
                "level": 40,
                "supporter": false,
                "light_level": 370,
                "hide_age": false,
                "profanity_ok_formatted": null,
                "computed_avatar_api": "img/default-avatar.png",
                "computed_avatar_chat": "https://www.the100.io/default-avatar.png",
                "developer_badge": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3559084,
            "user_id": 103209,
            "gaming_session_id": 831354,
            "reserve_spot": false,
            "user": {
                "id": 103209,
                "gamertag": "Martensitic",
                "age": 33,
                "level": 40,
                "supporter": false,
                "light_level": 394,
                "hide_age": false,
                "profanity_ok_formatted": "Profanity OK",
                "computed_avatar_api": "https://pwntastic-avatar-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/avatar/103209/main_a_print_above_the_rest_62_photos1_1396458281.jpg",
                "computed_avatar_chat": "https://pwntastic-avatar-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/avatar/103209/thumb_a_print_above_the_rest_62_photos1_1396458281.jpg",
                "developer_badge": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3559032,
            "user_id": 111897,
            "gaming_session_id": 831354,
            "reserve_spot": false,
            "user": {
                "id": 111897,
                "gamertag": "ini5o",
                "age": 29,
                "level": 40,
                "supporter": true,
                "light_level": 397,
                "hide_age": false,
                "profanity_ok_formatted": "Profanity OK",
                "computed_avatar_api": "https://pwntastic-avatar-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/avatar/111897/main_500x500.jpg",
                "computed_avatar_chat": "https://pwntastic-avatar-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/avatar/111897/thumb_500x500.jpg",
                "developer_badge": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3558957,
            "user_id": 101605,
            "gaming_session_id": 831354,
            "reserve_spot": false,
            "user": {
                "id": 101605,
                "gamertag": "TheMesso",
                "age": 30,
                "level": 40,
                "supporter": false,
                "light_level": 387,
                "hide_age": false,
                "profanity_ok_formatted": "Profanity OK",
                "computed_avatar_api": "https://pwntastic-avatar-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/avatar/101605/main_dramatic-eagle.jpg",
                "computed_avatar_chat": "https://pwntastic-avatar-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/avatar/101605/thumb_dramatic-eagle.jpg",
                "developer_badge": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3558942,
            "user_id": 133819,
            "gaming_session_id": 831354,
            "reserve_spot": false,
            "user": {
                "id": 133819,
                "gamertag": "richmanbri713",
                "age": 31,
                "level": 40,
                "supporter": false,
                "light_level": 387,
                "hide_age": false,
                "profanity_ok_formatted": "Profanity OK",
                "computed_avatar_api": "img/default-avatar.png",
                "computed_avatar_chat": "https://www.the100.io/default-avatar.png",
                "developer_badge": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I've tried so many different ways of calling the data but I'm quite new to this & could use some help. I would like to be able to pull one aspect of the data & store it in a variable if thats possible. If you wouldn't mind explaining things instead of just fixing it as I would like to learn it would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object".  You can create a **JavaScript** object to store the values retrieved from a JSON string, though....  For example, `var theData = JSON.parse(body);  var firstSession = theData[0].confirmed_sessions[0];`.... etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, the only thing I hadn't done was add the [0] to the end of the variable & that has fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace this line:

```
const context = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, 1);
```

by

```
const context = JSON.parse(body);
```

and now you will have returned object in `context` variable.